# Rails 4: set layout equal to false in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In a Rails 4 app I am trying to set the layout to `false` or `nil`. I tried this from inside my controller:

```
render :layout => false
```

But that gives this error:

```
undefined method `render'.
```

How can I stop this controller from using the default layout file?

Comment: Where are you calling `render` from? If it is in an action (method) in the controller then what you've done should be fine. Maybe provide more code or a trace of the error.

Comment: I have this in the controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable layout for a controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  layout false
  ...
end
```

Comment: @Lumbee, it should be `layout: false` not `nil`.

Answer (score 6):

### Scenario 1: To disable layout for *all the actions of a controller* use it as:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
   layout false  ## Note it is not within any action

   def create
   ...
   end

...
end
```

### Scenario 2: To disable layout *for a specific action* of a controller use it as:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
   ...
   render layout: false
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thanks for appreciating. :)

Comment: @Mohamad Thanks for formatting my answer. I see that you corrected Vee's answer. Don't you think that actually defeats the efforts of other users who posted correct answer in the first place. Its a waste of time also.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Helping someone out is never a waste of time. We should strive for quality, and correcting an answer is part of that. The OP made a comment below that answer I corrected. The right thing to do was to guide him and fix the answer. At worst it does no harm. Perhaps my intervention swayed the accepted answer, but this is a secondary consideration, and the SO community is quite adept at letting the cream rise to the top.

Comment: @Mohamad I agree that we are all here to help each other but we do want to get rewarded for efforts. Thats what SO reputation is for. Also, take a look at your timestamp when you formatted my answer vs when you corrected wrong answer. You can tell my correct answer was already there. Also, Craig Kaminsky's answer was available for evaluation by OP. I don't want to drag the conversaion but it wasn't fair.

Comment: @KirtiThorat you should take this up with the OP, not me. And you have been rewarded by two votes; that's how most reputation is gained--not through accepted answers. That's the prerogative of the OP, even if he/she wants to accept a wrong answer, or a lesser quality one. There's nothing we can do about it. On the other hand, the community will judge answers through votes and you won that battle. I think you ought to consider the bigger picture rather than 15 points of rep. There's my two cents.

Comment: @KirtiThorat for the record, I would never edit anything substantial. That was a very subtle and minor mistake in vee's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is to render nothing for a particular method (action) in a controller. This should work based on the output you linked to in the pastie under @vee's answer:

```
def new
  # code for the sessions#new controller#method
  render nothing: true
end
```

**EDIT**: This answer assumes that you do not want to render your actual view template ... if you really do not want to render a layout (versus a view template), @vee's response is the one.